# mysqlinstanceconfig and Disable Strict mode

Tags: mysql, deployment

I want to deploy mysql silently.

The server was installed quietly using this command line:

`msiexec /i "d:\mysql-essential-5.1.34-win32.msi" INSTALLDIR="D:\mysql" DATADIR="D:\mysql_data" /qn`

No problem.

After that I had to run mysqlinstanceconfig quietly too. I used the following command line:

```
"D:\mysql\bin\mysqlinstanceconfig.exe" -i -q ServiceName=MySQL AddBinToPath=yes ServerType=SERVER DatabaseType=MYISAM ConnectionUsage=DSS Port=3306 StrictMode=no Charset=utf8 RootPassword=mypass
```

Despite setting `StrictMode=no` (I want to disable Strict Mode), It does not worked because I have still the Strict mode enabled when I run this query on the server:

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'sql_mode';
```

I got this:

```
sql_mode="STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION"
```

Normally I should have:

```
sql_mode = ""
```

Is there something wrong with the mysqlinstanceconfig.exe command line ?

Comment: it would use the default values and i concure that is the right choiec fro strict mode, so if you need other  values, replace or rewrite my.ini

Comment: replacing my.ini is risky as the user can choose to install mysql on another drive.

Comment: Rewriting it at deployment is tedious and can lead to errors too as the installation drive is very important for my.ini

This is intended for the end user.

what is strange is when you use the user interface and you uncheck strict mode, it works as intended !! but in silent mode it use default value despite StrictMode=no

may be =no is not the right value to pass to the installer ?? Help please

Comment: you know which data folder will be used, so you will no problem of finding it the relace is fast and will go without errors, you havbe at the start a default my.ini and that looks always the same

Comment: So you suggest replacing line sql_mode="STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION" with sql_mode = '' on the ini file. right ?

Comment: yes give it a try